Empty space when creating an AlertDialog, only on Oppo phones
I was just trying to migrate my application from a Realme to an Oppo and everything looked fine until I noticed the displayed dialogs were not centered. Here is the example (I will only talk about the loading dialog but is a common problem to all dialogs):
Not centered dialog
My code for creating the Dialog is:
public class GenericAlert extends DialogFragment {

    public static final int LOADING_ALERT = 0;
    public static final int SENDING_ALERT = 1;
    public static final int ERROR_ALERT = 2;

    private int alertType;

    private boolean showing = false;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        int layoutToSet;
        switch (alertType) {
            case LOADING_ALERT: layoutToSet = R.layout.loading_alert_layout; break;
            case SENDING_ALERT: layoutToSet = R.layout.sending_alert_layout; break;
            case ERROR_ALERT: layoutToSet = R.layout.error_alert_layout; break;
            default: layoutToSet = R.layout.error_alert_layout; break;
        }


        View loadingAlertLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutToSet, null);
        builder.setView(loadingAlertLayout);

        if (alertType == SENDING_ALERT) {
            builder.setCancelable(false);
        }

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        return alert;
    }
    ...
}

I disabled the transparent background to see how much space was the dialog using: Not centered dialog with white background
Here is my XML file loading_alert_layout.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/less_round_corners_white_borders"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/loading_animation"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:padding="10dp"/>
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_weight=".7"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Cargando"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"/>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Se están recibiendo los datos, por favor, espere."/>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

I'm using both physical phones to test my app and I want to get rid of that annoying space.
I've tried almost everything that goes through my mind, with no luck, such as setting LayoutParams when inflating the View, requesting the FEATURE_NO_TITLE, changing the root view from a linear layout to a relative layout, constraint layout, and so on, and nothing seems to help me delete that empty space, that only occurs on the Oppo phone, not my Realme phone.
Note: When changing the root view, I've noticed the spacing does change when using differents views, here are some results I've got with views with just 10 dp padding, a red background, and match_parent and wrap_content values for layout_width and layout_height respectively:
LinearLayoutCompat, ConstraintLayout, AppCompatTextView, AppCompatButton
Seriously, I have no clue why this is happening and I've run out of ideas. Also, this is my first question here on StackOverflow, so be free to point out any mistakes I've made in my writing.
EDIT:
I just got to the conclusion it is a bug, so I solved it by adding a RelativeLayout as the root of the alert layout, set its gravity to center and its width and height to match_parent. It is not an answer to the problem, but it is at least a quick fix to get it working.

Have you tested your app on an official Android SDK emulator, to confirm which behavior is the correct one?

@CommonsWare Yes, I have launched my app on a virtual Pixel 8 with Android 14 and Android 13 and everything worked as intended on both (like on my Realme). By the way, the Oppo I am not able to get it working is an A96, if that helps.
